# Should I use high-resolution time types as parameters to avoid duration_casts?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, c++-chrono

I read that if the highest resolution type your program uses is, say, `milliseconds` and this type will cover the whole range your values are in, you should stick with it mostly, to avoid having `duration_casts` everywhere.
Instead you would have only one, inside the function, if all you need is a precision of, let's say, `seconds`.

However, for *return types* of functions you would conversely return the lowest resolution possible, to have the lowest possible amount of duration_casts (and here even optimal performance, since you would do the conversion anyway in this case).

Unfortunately I didn't find a source that covers this issue comprehensively (or really, in any way). Is this the way `std::chrono` should be used (assuming one is not eager about the last possible bit of performance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a lot one can say in general about this strategy except that *yes*, you don't want to needlessly litter your code with `duration_cast`.  Reserve `duration_cast` only for those conversions where you want to truncate the precision.  And in those cases recognize that `duration_cast` truncates towards zero.  C++17 introduces 3 other truncation strategies:

- `floor`: truncate towards negative infinity
- `ceil`: truncate towards positive infinity
- `round`: truncate towards nearest, towards even on tie

(If you are in C++11/14 you can grab these handy utilities [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html)).

And certainly if `milliseconds` is the finest precision you want to deal with, taking `milliseconds` as parameter types is a good strategy.

Using a coarser precision for return types might be good for some applications, but probably not for all.  Consider:

```
seconds process(milliseconds input);
```

`process` is some function that takes a `duration` `input`, performs some operation on it, and returns the `duration` output.  And in this example I've chosen a coarser precision than the input (`seconds`).  Presumably, at some point I've truncated the precision of the input, and in the process lost information.

Now if the purpose of `process` is to truncate precision, this is perfectly fine.  But if the purpose of `process` is something else and you're just returning `seconds` so that clients can do either of:

```
milliseconds result1 = process(input);
seconds      result2 = process(input);
```

then you may not be doing the client any favors.  Certainly the syntax for obtaining `result2` is very clean.  But you've also taken away the choice of this client on the direction of truncation (down, up, nearest, etc.).  Maybe that is a good thing for your application.  But it won't be a good thing for everyone, and thus not for a general purpose library.

As another example, lets look at the return type of one of the functions in `<chrono>` itself:

```
template<class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2>
constexpr
common_type_t<duration<Rep1, Period1>, duration<Rep2, Period2>>
operator+(const duration<Rep1, Period1>& lhs,
          const duration<Rep2, Period2>& rhs);
```

In this example the function (`operator+`) returns the *finest* precision from its inputs as opposed to the coarsest, in an effort to not loose *any* information.  The client is free to truncate that result if desired.  For those who aren't familiar with `common_type_t`, this is consistent with:

```
constexpr
milliseconds
operator+(const seconds& lhs, const milliseconds& rhs);
```